# Why the server answer RST right after receiving SYN from the client?

Tags: tcp, wireshark, handshake, modbus-tcp, syn

Why the server(i.e modbus tcp slave) answer RST right after receiving SYN from the client?

Here are the packets captured by `Wireshark`:

```
  1 09:58:55.773863730 192.168.0.168         192.168.0.21          TCP      66     39110 → 502 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 WS=128
  2 09:58:55.774090423 192.168.0.21          192.168.0.168         TCP      60     502 → 39110 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0
  3 09:58:55.774194303 192.168.0.168         192.168.0.21          TCP      66     39112 → 502 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 WS=128
  4 09:58:55.774298582 192.168.0.21          192.168.0.168         TCP      60     502 → 39112 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0
  5 10:01:35.548023265 192.168.0.168         192.168.0.21          TCP      66     39118 → 502 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 WS=128
  6 10:01:35.548248696 192.168.0.21          192.168.0.168         TCP      60     502 → 39118 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0
  7 10:01:35.548340993 192.168.0.168         192.168.0.21          TCP      66     39120 → 502 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 WS=128
  8 10:01:35.548446706 192.168.0.21          192.168.0.168         TCP      60     502 → 39120 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0
  9 10:02:09.279784987 192.168.0.168         192.168.0.21          TCP      66     39126 → 502 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 WS=128
 10 10:02:09.279974571 192.168.0.21          192.168.0.168         TCP      60     502 → 39126 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0
 11 10:02:09.280092319 192.168.0.168         192.168.0.21          TCP      66     39128 → 502 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 WS=128
 12 10:02:09.280196486 192.168.0.21          192.168.0.168         TCP      60     502 → 39128 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0
```

Update:
The server really listens to the port.
I confirm that by netstat -atn | grip 502( and returns tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:502             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN ) on the server side.

And `telnet 192.168.0.21 502` returns `Connected to 192.168.02.21`.

Comment: Because nothing was listening at that IP:port. This is a 'connection refused'.

Comment: @user207421 The server really listens to the port.I confirm that by `netstat -atn | grip 502`( and returns `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:502             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
`) on the server side. And `telnet 192.168.0.21 502` returns `Connected to 192.168.02.21`.